JavaFX dialog with long title visible
I'm trying to create a javaFX dialog with the title completely visible even if the content is "shorter".
Dialog<?> dialog = new Dialog<>();
        dialog.setTitle("A very very long title to see if ellipsis are present. You're still here? No ellipsis for you, then");
        DialogPane dPane = dialog.getDialogPane();
        dPane.setContent(new Button("Close"));
        dPane.autosize();
        dialog.showAndWait();

Trying to run this code this is the output:

I've already tried to "calculate" the dimension of the title text with this method and changing the dimension of the dialog during the "onShown" event:
public static double getWidth(String title) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(title)) {
            return 0D;
        }
        Text text = new Text(title);
        return text.getLayoutBounds().getWidth() + 10D;
    }

with no avail.
The desired dimension would be the max between title and content.
Is there a way to do it?
Thank you.

Write an MCVE.

Consider an abbreviated title, and letDialog::setHeaderText handle the long String; the DialogPane grow to fit.

@trashgod this works, but is there no other way?

Another way? As the stage is owned by the platform, I'd remain skeptical. Also consider the user experience: a screen-filling dialog with one, long, impenetrable title vs. a brief, trenchant title with a more illuminating header that word-wraps in the dialog which automatically adjusts to the platform.
